# I just deployed my Vite React site but my icons/images aren't deployed

Tags: reactjs, frontend, web-deployment, vite, netlify

I deployed my Vite React site on Netlify but my skill icons aren't rendered!!
[image: Screenshot o site.]
[Here's the site.](https://mjshubham21-portfolio.netlify.app/).
I did execute npm run build before deploying, I got the dist folder and deployed that on Netlify.
But at first the assets folder didn't had the icons so I added it in the assets (of dist folder) folder too, but no success!!
Please help.

I wanna render my skill icons of my portfolio site.

Comment: Could You provide link to the repo please?

Comment: https://github.com/mjshubham21/Mjshubham21Portfolio

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to move your `assets` directory into the `public` directory, and you need to remove `./src` from the source path of the various img files. Something like:

```js
{
    id: 1,
    icon: "/assets/html5.svg",
    iconName: "HTML",
},
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked in my local host, but not on my deployed site... https://mjshubham21.live/  thoughts?? console says " Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 () " for the icons...

Answer (score 3):

Referring to the `Vite` [documentation](https://vitejs.dev/guide/assets.html#importing-asset-as-url) You should put Your **assets files** into `public` folder directly.

Notice that:

> You should always reference public assets using root absolute path -
> for example, `public/icon.png` should be referenced in source code as
> `/icon.png`.

**folder&file** structure:

[image]

---

**Skills.jsx** (*icons*)

```
import React from "react";
// import Skill from "./Skill";

function Skills() {
  return (
    <>
      <section className="skills">
        <div className="card">
          <div className="content">
            <img className="skillIcon" src="/html5.svg" alt="Icon" />
            <p className="skillName">HTML</p>
          </div>
          <div className="content">
            <img className="skillIcon" src="/css3.svg" alt="Icon" />
            <p className="skillName">CSS3</p>
          </div>
          <div className="content">
            <img className="skillIcon" src="/js.svg" alt="Icon" />
            <p className="skillName">JavaScript</p>
          </div>
          <div className="content">
            <img className="skillIcon" src="/react.svg" alt="Icon" />
            <p className="skillName">ReactJs</p>
          </div>
          <div className="content">
            <img className="skillIcon" src="/mongodb.svg" alt="Icon" />
            <p className="skillName">MongoDB</p>
          </div>
          <div className="content">
            <img className="skillIcon" src="/express.svg" alt="Icon" />
            <p className="skillName">ExpressJs</p>
          </div>
          <div className="content">
            <img className="skillIcon" src="/github.svg" alt="Icon" />
            <p className="skillName">GitHub</p>
          </div>
          <div className="content">
            <img className="skillIcon" src="/node.svg" alt="Icon" />
            <p className="skillName">NodeJs</p>
          </div>
          <div className="content">
            <img className="skillIcon" src="/password.svg" alt="Icon" />
            <p className="skillName">Authentication</p>
          </div>
          <div className="content">
            <img className="skillIcon" src="/api.svg" alt="Icon" />
            <p className="skillName">API</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </>
  );
}

export default Skills;
```

---

**Intro.jsx**  (*hero.gif*)

```
import React from "react";
import hero from "/hero.gif";
function Intro() {
  return (
    <>
      <main>
        <section id="intro" className="hero">
          <div className="heroText">
            <p className="topData">Hey, I'm</p>
            <h1 className="title">Shubham Pawar</h1>
            <p className="heroData">I'm a MERN stack Developer.</p>
            <button className="btn">Contact Me</button>
            <button className="btn">Resume</button>
          </div>
          <div className="heroImg">
            <img className="heroGif" src={hero} alt="hero img" />
          </div>
        </section>
      </main>
    </>
  );
}

export default Intro;
```

---

**Footer.jsx** (*icons*)

```
import React from "react";

function Footer() {
  return (
    <>
      <footer className="Footer">
        <div className="footer-right">
          <a href="#"></a>
          <a href="#">
            <img className="footerIcon" src="/linkedin2.png" alt="linkedIn" />
          </a>
          <a href="#">
            <img className="footerIcon" src="/github2.png" alt="GitHub" />
          </a>
          <a href="#">
            <img className="footerIcon" src="/instagram.png" alt="Instagram" />
          </a>
          <a href="#">
            <img className="footerIcon" src="/twitter.png" alt="Twitter" />
          </a>
        </div>

        <div className="footer-left">
          <p className="footer-links">
            <a className="link-1" href="#">
              Home
            </a>

            <a href="#about">About</a>

            <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
          </p>
          <p>
            @mjshubham21 Copyright &copy; {new Date().getFullYear()} All Rights
            Reserved.
          </p>
        </div>
      </footer>
    </>
  );
}

export default Footer;
```

---

**Output in browser**:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it worked in my local host but not on the live site... https://mjshubham21.live/

Comment: @mjshubham21 Are You sure ? :-) I see icons ...:-P

Comment: Yeah it was fixed...

Answer (score 0):

You should always reference public assets using root absolute path - for example, `public/icon.png` should be referenced in the source code as `/icon.png`.

The above lines saved me from further frustrations of vite+React deployment