# I am deploying my website in netlify server Its successfully deploying but no images are coming

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, vite, netlify

I am making  webapp in which I am using the techstack as vite,react,tailwind.
I deployed it in netlify server deployment is perfect but m not able to See the images.

[image]

In my local server its showing and when I look into my dist folder in that there is an asset folder but most of the images are missing.

Here is my code

[image]

Tried to google but could not find solve the issue

Comment: Shouldn't the `assets` be in the `public` folder, instead of `src`?

Comment: But I am mentioning the path and its showing in local server

Comment: In local the images will be displayed as you have the `src` folder in local. But once you build, the `dist` folder will not contain the `src` folder. Please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74912693/20222272)